# How to automatically restart a disconnected (screen) command line command

Tags: ssh

I run some web stuff on a pi, but am behind CGNAT so can't directly accept incoming connections.

So on the PI I run screen to have a detached command line that runs reverse SSH to port forward from a cheap server I have with an ISP.

However fairly regularly the reverse SSH crashed out

```
ssh -N -R 443:localhost:443 -R 80:localhost:80 -R 53:localhost:53 -R 8090:localhost:8090 -R 8443:localhost:8443 -R 1883:localhost:1883 -R 9001:localhost:9001 root@<ip-address>
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

Rather than just typing the SSH command, and having to reattach, restart when it crashes, what is the easiest way to make it automatically restart?

Comment: I would put the command in a while loop.  Perhaps sleeping between attempts.  Off topic here.